# "Explicit" 1-1 Self-relations in Prisma

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, prisma

Say I have a model called `Room` and another called `Path`.

Each `Room` is connected to each other by `Path`s. The `Path` is not one-way, you can go from one `Room` to another `Room` via a `Path`, and vice versa through the same `Path`.

Each `Room` and `Path` must have a name attribute. This is to identify `Room`s and `Path`s as different from each other, like how two `Path`s can connect to the same two rooms (eg. a path that goes through the window and another that goes through a door)

**How would I model this in Prisma in a PostgreSQL database?**

Best attempt so far (but ultimately fails):

```
model Room {
    id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
    name String
    connected_paths Path[] // ???
}

model Path {
    id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
    name String
    location_1 Location // ???
    location_2 Location // ???
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run into same issue once, but I was using SQLServier after a lot of research I ended up making something like this:

```
model Room {
  id    Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  name  String
  paths RoomPath[]
}

model Path {
  id    Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  name  String
  rooms RoomPath[]
}

model RoomPath {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  Room   Room @relation(fields: [roomId], references: [id])
  roomId Int
  Path   Path @relation(fields: [pathId], references: [id])
  pathId Int
}
```